# Javascript predefined local variables for in

Tags: javascript, ecma

For example

```
function mount(cb) {
    this.payload = 5;
    this.items = [1,2,3];
    cb.apply(this);
}

function render() {
    var _this = this;
    this.items.map(function(num){
        return _this.payload + num
    })
}

mount(render);
```

is it possible to pre-define a variable _this in 'mount' for 'render', dont use function args,  what could I write

```
function render() {
    this.items.map(function(num){
        _this.payload + num
    })
}
```

_this just for example, that is, pre-define local variables for a user-defined function, which are the same from call to call, that is, a constant

Answer (score 1):

Arrow function will work since it preserves the scope

```
function render() {
    this.items.map((num) => {
        return this.payload + num
    })
}
```

Also it can be shortened:

```
function render() {
    this.items.map(num => this.payload + num)
}
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions